# Change the color of a line in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want the second line, change to another color.

My code is as follows :

```
 private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRTBOnDifferentThread("stackoverflow.com" + Environment.NewLine+"stackoverflow.org" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void UpdateRTBOnDifferentThread(string message)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
        {
            var newExternalParagraph = new Paragraph(new Run(message)) {Foreground = Brushes.Black};
            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(newExternalParagraph);
            return null;
        }), null);
    }
```

The second line is: "stackoverflow.org"

I want to change the color after the enter text

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `String.Split` to break the lines inside your `UpdateRTBOnDifferentThread` method, or you can have this method accept an array of strings. Then you can iterate the array and add N Paragraph objects or N Run objects inside the same paragraph, and control the foreground of each string separately.